# Getting minute difference between two timestamps in mysql using TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: php, mysql

I have my SQL statement like this trying to get the difference in 2 timestamps greater than 10 minutes. "timestamp" is a column in MYSQL which I hold a timstamp as such "1365793346"

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timestamp,NOW()) AS thisisit
```

Im not sure if using "AS thisisit" is a current function of TIMESTAMPDIFF but I was able to find some old posts that how it used as such. I am not sure if its supported anymore because I an a syntax error at "AS thisisit"

I have also tried using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timestamp,NOW()) > 10
```

Where I am not sure what is going on is first is my syntax correct and second how to do associate this query with a label so I can echo it. My full PhP code looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timestamp,NOW()) > 10
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[0];
}
```

I was assuming I could use something like this to echo the results, but I get nothing to the screen. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AS thisisit` in this case have to be used to set an alias to your column.

So, you should use the following:

```
SELECT timestamp AS 'thisisit'
    FROM table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, timestamp, NOW()) > 10;
```